# Cannot Load external swf into the main swf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash

I am having trouble to load external swf into my main swf. What could be the problem. I am using flex sdk 4.5.0 and already changed use-network setting to false. I doenst give any security error though, I tried also try catch block

Comment: Are you using the debugger player?  No error messages, not even in flashlog.txt?

Comment: It can load images but when i load swf it just shows that it started loading but doesnt continues. How to set up flex sdk 4.5 to use flex debugger?  I use flex sdk just to compile

Comment: Added locations to this configuration http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html but now it just gives everything blank

Comment: How are you trying to load the SWF?  SWFLoader?  Or as a Module?  Please share some code.

Comment: I use as3 API for loading swf , Loader class

Comment: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/

Comment: I found that the main swf can load only swf files that are in the same folder. So for example if i have the external swf in subfolder of the folder where main swf resides, it refuses to load it, althoug i added permissions in flash configuration. Any idea how to resolve this?